# Is it possible to trigger specific actions at certain times or locations?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

For example:

- I want to trigger flight mode at 12:00 am and deactivate it at 6:00
  am automatically.
- As long as I am at home, I don't like to enter a password every time I use my phone so the lock screen is deactivated. But when I get outside the lock screen with password is activated.

I am talking here about Windows 10 mobile.

Comment: thats a great idea! post that in feedback app. i ill surely upvote it. i guess we will get this feature via cortana in future!!!!

Answer (score 2):

**This is not possible at the present time.**

However some actions may be possible in near future(with Cortana). This is possible if Microsoft decides to implement it. Cortana can already perform actions like turning ON/OFF WiFi, etc... It also provides location as well as time based remainders.

I suggest you add this as a feedback to Microsoft. I will surely upvote it when I come across such feedbacks.

> I want to trigger flight mode at 12:00 am and deactivate it at 6:00 am
>   automatically.

A feature request has been made for Scheduled power on and off. If that could solve your issue upvote their feedbacks in the Windows Feedback app.

> As long as I am at home, I don't like to enter a password every time I
>   use my phone so the lock screen is deactivated. But when I get outside
>   the lock screen with password is activated.

I don't think that this feature will be implemented as this feature may reduce the security of the phone. For example, to unlock your phone all I have to do is make its GPS think that it is in your home.That can be done if one can access your hardware.